# DataGrid bound to ObservableCollection doesn't update immediately after values changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection named PingStatisticCollection. The IPs are pinged periodically. Success is written immediately to the item of the ObservableCollection as 0 for success, else 1. The visual update of the UI last until the test is completed. When a test fails, the test of the next IP has to wait 1000 ms, if more IPs aren't pingable the update of the UI lasts even longer. How can I update the UI immediately after testing a single IP in the loop?

Parts of my View:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdStatistic" ItemsSource="{Binding PingStatisticCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="SelectedPingStatisticElement" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFFFE880"  >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP" Width="100" Binding="{Binding IP}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="70">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Ping</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Name="imagegreen" Source="/Resources/green.png" Width="20" Height="20"  Margin="5,0" />
                    <Image Name="imagered"  Source="/Resources/red.png"   Width="20" Height="20"  Margin="5,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=actPingSuccess, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="0">
                        <Setter TargetName="imagegreen" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="imagered" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=actPingSuccess, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="1">
                        <Setter TargetName="imagegreen" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="imagered" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

//extracts from ViewModel:

//Command bound to a button to test functionality

```
void OnTestIP(object sender) 
{
  string sIP;
  bool bSuccess;

  foreach (var p in PingStatisticCollection)  // load from database
  {
    SelectedPingStatisticElement = p;
    lock(p)
    {
      bSuccess = PingHost(p.IP, 1000 );
      SavePingSuccess(p, bSuccess);
// actual success and last 5 tests determine red, yellow, green iconcolor
      DetermineIconColors(p, PingStatisticCollection);
    }
  }
}

private ObservableCollection<PingStatistic> _PingStatisticCollection;
public ObservableCollection<PingStatistic> PingStatisticCollection
{
    get { return _PingStatisticCollection; }
    set
    { _PingStatisticCollection = value;      OnPropertyChanged("PingStatisticCollection"); }
}

//extracts from Model: 

class PingStatistic: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  private string _IP;
  public string IP     // +
  {
    get { return _IP; }
    set
    {   if (value != _IP)
        {   _IP = value; OnPropertyChanged("IP");}
    }
  }

  public int actPingSuccess       
  {
    get { return _actPingSuccess; }
    set
    {
      _actPingSuccess = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("actPingSuccess");
    }
  } 
}
```

At the moment the IconColors for all IPs are updated after each IP is visited. I want to update the color immediately without delay after visiting and evaluating it. Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks, Bernd

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `foreach`, try using `Parallel.ForEach` along with Task.

```
await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(strings, s => { DoSomething(s); //Update the status of IP here));
```

Comment: Dear Brian, I was really happy to get an answer to my problem so fast. As my knowlage on ansynchronas programming is not very profound I was very happy to fulfill my task with the following code:

void OnTestIP(object sender)
{   
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(PingStatisticCollection);
}

I must confess that I do not understand your solution in total. Thank you very much for your help, Bernd